# How do I select a record whose timestamp is the most recent

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a mysql db which one of the columns is of type timestamp. And the records look like this

[image]

How do I select the most recent timestamp in a query and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY CREATED_TS LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY created_ts DESC LIMIT 1
```

PS: you should use hashed passwords rather than plain-text ones

Comment: Never use *, always define the fields.

Comment: @xQbert: never say never. No reason to read lectures about good sql practices in every sql-related question. When OP will ask about best practices, please do, but don't be annoying now

Answer (score 0):

I guess its better to index the sequence ID and get the max from there. Getting max of your timestamp will run into real performance issues when your table grows big.